# Add records to table where there is commonality in data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains a list of purchased items, and replacement items.  Where there is commonality in the replacement items across purchased items for the same buyer, I want to identify the possible matching pairs that don't currently exist in the table.

For example the table may have this data:

```
+----------+---------+----------
|  Buyer_ID| Buy_ID  |Rplc_ID  |
+----------+---------+----------
| 12345    |   A     |    C    |
| 12345    |   A     |    D    |
| 12345    |   B     |    C    |
+----------+---------+----------
```

However Because Buy_IDs A and B both have C in common, I want to identify what is missing from B that A has...

```
+----------+---------+----------
|  Buyer_ID| Buy_ID  |Rplc_ID  |
+----------+---------+----------
| 12345    |   A     |    C    |
| 12345    |   A     |    D    |
| 12345    |   B     |    C    |
| 12345    |   B     |    D    |
+----------+---------+----------
```

This is almost like a Ven Diagram in that I need to identify where there is overlap of Rplc_Ids across different Buy_IDs.  I then need to assimilate mismatches between these two so any overlap across Rplc_IDs forces commonality between all Buy_IDs with any commonality.

[image: Ven1]

[image: Ven2]

This is a fairly benign example.  What I'm struggling with is the various levels that can occur.  For example if I have 10 Buy_Ids, each with 10 Rplc_IDs, and there is commonality across pairs of Buy_IDs, how can I programmatically query this?

I've tried various techniques with dynamic SQL and loops to identify and append records into a table to serially add to the A/B overlap, but this has been of limited success.  I'd imagine a CTE could do this, but I cannot formulate a query than can effectively do this.

I'm providing a more elaborate example here.  Note the first `@Replacements` table contains the initial data.  The `@Results` table shows what I hope to return.

```
DECLARE @Replacements TABLE
(
 Buyer_ID       VARCHAR(10),
 BUY_ID         VARCHAR(10),
 RPL_ID         VARCHAR(10)

 )

DECLARE @Results TABLE
(
 Buyer_ID       VARCHAR(10),
 BUY_ID         VARCHAR(10),
 RPL_ID         VARCHAR(10)

 )

Insert into @Replacements 
VALUES
('10003','A','D'),
('10003','A','E'),
('10003','A','F'),
('10003','A','B'),
('10003','A','C'),
('10003','B','B'),
('10003','C','D'),
('10003','C','E'),
('10003','C','F'),
('10003','C','B')


Insert into @Results 
VALUES
('10003','A','D'),
('10003','A','E'),
('10003','A','F'),
('10003','A','B'),
('10003','A','C'),
('10003','B','B'),
('10003','C','D'),
('10003','C','E'),
('10003','C','F'),
('10003','C','B'),
('10003','B','D'),
('10003','B','E'),
('10003','B','F'),
('10003','B','C'),
('10003','C','C')

Select * from @Replacements ORDER BY RPL_ID, BUY_ID
Select * from @Results ORDER BY RPL_ID, BUY_ID
```

And the results:
@Replacements:

```
Buyer_ID    RPL_ID  BUY_ID
    10003   A        B
    10003   A        C
    10003   A        D
    10003   A        E
    10003   A        F
    10003   B        B
    10003   C        B
    10003   C        D
    10003   C        E
    10003   C        F
```

Expected results @Results

```
Buyer_ID    RPL_ID  BUY_ID
10003   A        B
10003   A        C
10003   A        D
10003   A        E
10003   A        F
10003   B        B
10003   B        C
10003   B        D
10003   B        E
10003   B        F
10003   C        B
10003   C        C
10003   C        D
10003   C        E
10003   C        F
```

Thinking through this in steps, Buyer_ID A and C have in common Rplc_ID B, D, E, F.  Because A has C, Buyer_ID C must also have C.

Because Buyer_ID A, B, C have in common Rplc_ID B, Buyer_ID B must receive RPLC_ID that Buyer_ID A and C have, thus Buyer_ID B is given Rplc_ID C, D, E, F.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this give you what you need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    R.Buyer_ID
    , R.BUY_ID
    , R2.RPL_ID
FROM
    @Replacements R
    JOIN @Replacements R1 ON
        R.Buyer_ID = R1.Buyer_ID
        AND R.RPL_ID = R1.RPL_ID
    JOIN @Replacements R2 ON
        R.Buyer_ID = R2.Buyer_ID
        AND R1.BUY_ID = R2.BUY_ID
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  That's exactly it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select distinct
       r.Buyer_ID
     , r.BUY_ID
     , r2.RPL_ID
  from @Replacements r
  join @Replacements r1
    on R1.RPL_ID = R.RPL_ID
  join @Replacements r2
    on r2.BUY_ID = r1.BUY_ID
 order by 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help above, this got me 99% of the way there.  However I found in some cases this matching process had to be iterated.

Here's the initial data load:

```
DECLARE @Replacements TABLE
(
 Buyer_ID       VARCHAR(10),
 BUY_ID         VARCHAR(10),
 RPL_ID         VARCHAR(10)

 )

DECLARE @Results TABLE
(
 Buyer_ID       VARCHAR(10),
 BUY_ID         VARCHAR(10),
 RPL_ID         VARCHAR(10)

 )

Insert into @Replacements 
VALUES
('10003','A','D'),
('10003','A','E'),
('10003','A','F'),
('10003','A','B'),
('10003','A','C'),
('10003','B','B'),
('10003','C','D'),
('10003','C','E'),
('10003','C','F'),
('10003','C','B'),

('10004','A','S'),
('10004','A','T'),
('10004','A','U'),
('10004','A','Z'),
('10004','B','S'),
('10004','B','T'),
('10004','B','U'),
('10004','B','V'),
('10004','B','W'),
('10004','C','V'),
('10004','C','W'),
('10004','C','X'),
('10004','D','X'),
('10004','D','Y'),
('10004','D','Z'),
('10004','E','P'),
('10004','E','Q'),
('10004','E','R'),
('10004','F','P'),
('10004','F','Q'),
('10004','F','R')




Insert into @Results 
VALUES
('10003','A','D'),
('10003','A','E'),
('10003','A','F'),
('10003','A','B'),
('10003','A','C'),
('10003','B','B'),
('10003','C','D'),
('10003','C','E'),
('10003','C','F'),
('10003','C','B'),
('10003','B','D'),
('10003','B','E'),
('10003','B','F'),
('10003','B','C'),
('10003','C','C'),

('10004','A','S'),
('10004','A','T'),
('10004','A','U'),
('10004','A','V'),
('10004','A','W'),
('10004','A','X'),
('10004','A','Y'),
('10004','A','Z'),
('10004','B','S'),
('10004','B','T'),
('10004','B','U'),
('10004','B','V'),
('10004','B','W'),
('10004','B','X'),
('10004','B','Y'),
('10004','B','Z'),
('10004','C','T'),
('10004','C','U'),
('10004','C','V'),
('10004','C','W'),
('10004','C','X'),
('10004','C','Y'),
('10004','C','Z'),
('10004','D','S'),
('10004','D','T'),
('10004','D','U'),
('10004','D','V'),
('10004','D','W'),
('10004','D','X'),
('10004','D','Y'),
('10004','D','Z'),
('10004','E','P'),
('10004','E','Q'),
('10004','E','R'),
('10004','F','P'),
('10004','F','Q'),
('10004','F','R')
```

If I were to run the following SQL script:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    R.Buyer_ID
    , R.BUY_ID
    , R2.RPL_ID
FROM
    @Replacements R
    JOIN @Replacements R1 ON
        R.Buyer_ID = R1.Buyer_ID
        AND R.RPL_ID = R1.RPL_ID
    JOIN @Replacements R2 ON
        R.Buyer_ID = R2.Buyer_ID
        AND R1.BUY_ID = R2.BUY_ID
```

and compare the results to what I would expect:

```
 Select RSLT.* 
 FROM @Results RSLT
 LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        R.Buyer_ID
        , R.BUY_ID
        , R2.RPL_ID
    FROM
        @Replacements R
        JOIN @Replacements R1 ON
            R.Buyer_ID = R1.Buyer_ID
            AND R.RPL_ID = R1.RPL_ID
        JOIN @Replacements R2 ON
            R.Buyer_ID = R2.Buyer_ID
            AND R1.BUY_ID = R2.BUY_ID)RPLC
  ON RSLT.Buyer_ID=RPLC.Buyer_ID
    and RSLT.BUY_ID=RPLC.BUY_ID
    and RSLT.RPL_ID=RPLC.RPL_ID
where RPLC.Buyer_ID IS NULL
```

I'm left with one missing record:

```
Buyer_ID    BUY_ID  RPL_ID
10004        B       Y
```

I found if I make the expression a CTE and self-join I get the results I'm ultimately after.  Frankly I'm not certain this isn't just a result of effectively running the query twice by wrapping it in a CTE or not.

```
;with cRSLT as (
SELECT DISTINCT
    R.Buyer_ID
    , R.BUY_ID
    , R2.RPL_ID
FROM
    @Replacements R
    JOIN @Replacements R1 ON
        R.Buyer_ID = R1.Buyer_ID
        AND R.RPL_ID = R1.RPL_ID
    JOIN @Replacements R2 ON
        R.Buyer_ID = R2.Buyer_ID
        AND R1.BUY_ID = R2.BUY_ID )

Select DISTINCT
    r.Buyer_ID,
    r.BUY_ID,
    r2.RPL_ID
from cRSLT r
  JOIN cRSLT r1 
    ON r.Buyer_ID=r1.Buyer_ID
     and r.RPL_ID=r1.RPL_ID
  JOIN cRSLT r2
    ON r.Buyer_ID=r2.Buyer_ID
     and r1.BUY_ID=r2.BUY_ID
ORDER BY r.Buyer_ID, r.BUY_ID, r2.RPL_ID
```